# How to convert InsertOneResult to string using Java mongoClient

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, micronaut

I have a method that inserts the record to the MongoDB collection as below

```
public Single<InsertOneResult> create(TagCommand model) {
        Tag tag = new Tag();
        tag.setName(model.name());
        return Single.fromPublisher(this.iRepository.getCollection(ConstantValues.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_COLLECTION_NAME, Tag.class)
                .insertOne(tag));
    }
```

Now on the calling method I need to map the inserted id to the other POJO class as shown below.

[image]

The values are shown below

[image]

Comment: See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/bson/org/bson/BsonObjectId.html#getValue()

Comment: @admlz635 I don't see those method in item

Comment: Use .getInsertedId() method in item (it returns a BsonObjectId, but keep in mind it could be null), then do .asObjectId() to get the id. Try with:
```item.getInsertedId().asObjectId().toString();```
or
```item.getInsertedId().asObjectId().getValue().toString();```

Comment: @admlz635 update the question please have a look. Cannot access BsonValue

Comment: Ignore that error, was due to the dependency. Thanks all good now

Comment: Well I have to use item.getInsertedId().asObjectId().getValue().toString() to get the string value

Answer (score 0):

The code as below works for me, just try it.

```
String id = ((BsonObjectId) insertOneResult.getInsertedId()).getValue().toHexString();
```